# Oracle 11.2.0.4.0 32 bits full client installation

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I need to install an Oracle Client on a Windows 2008 Server R2.
The client must be 32 bits since the application that it is going to use it only works under 32 bits.

I´m getting crazy knowing what specific packages I need to download and install. I can´t find what components I have to install to simply install the client and the ODBC drivers. I cannot believe that Oracle is so bad at this. Why cannot Oracle have a simple installer where you install everithing you need?, instead of having to donwload multiple packages, merging them and running console installers.

I´ve donwloaded and installed:

- ODAC112040Xcopy_32bit
- instantclient-basic-nt-11.2.0.4.0
- instantclient-odbc-nt-11.2.0.4.0

And I still cannot get the freaking ODBC driver to appear on the list of availables ODBC drivers on ODBC connections.

Can someone please tell me or point me out what do I have to install to accomplish this?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an Oracle, but a Microsoft Windows issue. When you install a 32-bit ODBC driver on a 64-bit operating system, and try to configure ODBC data sources from the Start menu or Control panel, it opens the utility (`C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32.exe`) for managing 64 bit drivers and data sources with them.

If you want to manage ODBC with a 32-bit driver, run this instead:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
```

Newer versions of Windows offer 2 seperate menu entries for managing 32-bit and 64-bit ODBC.

[image]

> Why cannot Oracle have a simple installer where you install everithing
>   you need?, instead of having to donwload multiple packages, merging
>   them and running console installers.

Here is the full, graphical installer (win32_11gR2_client.zip) for 11.2:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/112010-win32soft-098987.html

The 11.2.0.4 version can be downloaded from https://support.oracle.com/ with a valid support contract, which is required for downloading updates.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. The problem was the client version. I already was looking for 32 bit ODBC connection.